# VB.NET 'someObj' is not disposed along all exception paths - I don't want to dispose it. Is my approach wrong?

Tags: .net, vb.net, scope, dispose

VB.NET 2010, .NET 4

Hello,

I tried running code analysis the first time and found what it appears many others on SO doing the same have found:  an abundance of

> In method 'SomeMethod()', object
>   'SomeObject' is not disposed along all
>   exception paths. Call
>   System.IDisposable.Dispose on object
>   'SomeObject' before all references to
>   it are out of scope.

warnings ([CA2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx)).  I've read a bunch of other threads on this here on SO, most of which had to do with the object in question possibly throwing an exception outside of a try block etc.

But what about something like this?

```
Private SomeContainer As New Panel
Private Sub SomePopulatorMethod()
  '..stuff..'
  For i As Integer = 0 To 9
    Dim newLabel as New Label
    newLabel.Text = i.ToString
    SomeContainer.Controls.Add(newLabel)
  Next
  '..other stuff..'
End Sub
```

In that case, I don't *want* `newLabel` to be disposed since it should remain in the panel.  I do things like this when dynamically setting up a helper form where I create a bunch of textbox/label pairs to represent some data set.  Is this approach fundamentally wrong?  If so, how else should I go about it?  I'm actually (sort of) alright with just letting sleeping dogs lie, but warnings make me sad...  I'd like to do things right if only I could know how.

Any insight would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're not getting bit by the problem mentioned in the final paragraph of the MSDN article you linked to?

I can't say that your approach is incorrect, on the contrary. Generally speaking you shouldn't even have to worry about whether or not an object is disposable unless it somehow dictates that it needs to be used in a very specific way (as in with a `using(x) { ... }` block in C#). A stream for example implements IDisposable and can be used that way, or you can just call Close(), which is ultimately what it does when it's disposed.

Most Forms controls are components which by definition implement IDisposable... it would be pretty tiring if you had to keep track of all of them with try/catch blocks. If that warning is showing up because the VB compiler is inserting arithmetic overflow checks on everything then just turn off the checks or ignore the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but for anyone else who stumbles on this question like I did:

I believe the problem here is that Label will allocate unmanaged memory.  When .NET frees it, the unmanaged memory is **not** freed.  If you pass it to SomeContainer, then SomeContainer, when it is done with it, will call Dispose, which will free the unmanaged memory.  So you're fine if you get as far as the call to SomeContainer.Control.Add.  But if something somehow goes wrong with **newLabel.Text = i.ToString** the unmanaged memory is gone till your program stops.

What .NET wants you to do in this case is put a try block around the assignment and call Dispose if something goes wrong with it.  Now you can have no memory leak no matter how crazy your data gets.  (I'm have trouble seeing what can go wrong with that line, but I don't think you would have gotten the error if it was certain to work every time.)  I don't think programmers ought to have to worry about this stuff, but if you are using .NET and you can't afford a memory leak (like with a server program that runs for months at a time with very heavy use), it's probably a good idea to do everything precisely right.

**Update after doing more research:**

Forget the try/catch blocks.  Do this (swapping the last two lines):

```
Dim newLabel as New Label
SomeContainer.Controls.Add(newLabel)
newLabel.Text = i.ToString
```

Now when i.ToString bombs it's not your problem. SomeContainer already has newLabel and is responsible for calling Dispose on it.

Comment: Cheers for adding new clarity to an old issue. Thanks!